# sIFR multiple calls don't work :(

Tags: sifr

I'm trying to use sIFR on my menu and on my headers... but only one call works... the others that I put after never appear :(...

Can somebody help me ?

Note : I'm using the r436 and below is my code ...

```
   var segoe = {
        src: 'pathto/segoe.swf',
        ratios: [7, 1.58, 8, 1.49, 10, 1.5, 11, 1.45, 16, 1.46, 21, 1.44, 22, 1.41, 27, 1.42, 30, 1.41, 32, 1.4, 35, 1.41, 36, 1.4, 38, 1.39, 41, 1.4, 58, 1.39, 65, 1.38, 66, 1.39, 102, 1.38, 104, 1.37, 106, 1.38, 107, 1.37, 108, 1.38, 109, 1.37, 110, 1.38, 112, 1.37, 114, 1.38, 120, 1.37, 121, 1.38, 1.37]
    };
    sIFR.activate(segoe);

    sIFR.replace(segoe, {
        selector: '#header ul li a span.title',
        css: ['.sIFR-root { text-align: center; font-size:13px; letter-spacing:2; font-weight: bold; text-transform:uppercase; cursor: pointer; color:#FFFFFF; background-color:#0C2C39; margin:0 3px; }'],
        wmode: 'transparent'
    });
    sIFR.replace(segoe, {
        selector: 'h1',
        css: ['.sIFR-root { text-align: center; font-size:13px; letter-spacing:2; font-weight: bold; text-transform:uppercase; cursor: pointer; color:#000; background-color:#fff; margin:0 3px; }']
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I feel stupid now...

I wasn't properly calling the "sifr-config.js" file...

## -_-"

Sorry !

Comment: Note though that you can't replace the `li a span.title`, the link won't work reliably. You have to replace the `li` instead, so the `a` ends up inside the Flash movie.